# dateコマンドでEC2のシステムクロックを更新できない

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rhel

### 起きてる問題

AWS上で利用しているEC2サーバーのシステムクロックが、現在時刻とズレてしまっている。

```
$> date
2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 08:50:03 UTC
# 本当の現在時刻は2021/8/31 07:34:00 UTC
```

### 前提および利用環境

・Amazon EC2サーバーを利用
・OSは Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
・ntpdサービスは諸事情により利用不可

### やったこととぶち当たった壁

OSが古すぎるせいで、[Amazon Time Sync Service](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/news/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/)はインストールすら不可能。
ntpdサービスも制限されていて使えない。
5,6年前くらいからある、敏感なレガシーシステムでありOS再起動もできない。

最後に行き着いた先は、dateコマンドで手動で時刻を変更するという方法。
しかし、コマンドを実行しても、現在時刻がアップデートされません。

```
$> date
2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 08:50:03 UTC

$> date -s "2021-08-31 07:34:00"
2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 07:34:03 UTC

$> date
2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 08:50:03 UTC
# 更新できてない...
```

原因がわかりそうな方がいれば、どんな情報でも構わないのでお答えいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `hwclock` コマンドの実行結果も同じようにずれていますか？

Comment: hwclockコマンドを実行すると「既知のどんな方法でも、ハードウェア時計にアクセスできません。」というエラーが出てきてしまい、実行結果すら見ることができません。AWSの仕様なのかも...

Comment: AWS EC2 instance は virtual machine ですので hardware clock を持っていません。。。 参考までに、`cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource` を実行すると clock source が表示されます。

Comment: 参考情報ありがとうございます。ちなみに「jiffies」と表示されました。

Comment: rootユーザでdateコマンドを実行してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。rootユーザでのコマンド実行も試しております。

Comment: `timedatectl set-time HH:MM:SS`, `timedatectl status` などはどうでしょう？

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource` の実行結果に `xen` がありますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。timedatectlはコマンドが存在せず、yum installしても「パッケージが無い」とエラーが出ます。
`available_clocksource`には`xen`という文字はなく、`jiffies`とあります。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

解決できたので、ここに方法を記載しておきます。

#### そもそもズレが起きる原因

システムクロック、ハードウェアクロック共にズレが起きるのは仕方ない。
そのズレを定期的に修正するために、一般的にはntpdサービスが裏で躍動してる。
ただ、このサーバーの場合、外のntpサーバーを参照できない状況であり、実質ntpによる定期的修正はできない状況。
このような理由で、ちょっとずつ時間のズレは起きるようになってる。

#### 今回の解決方法

システムクロックを修正するには、今回の場合だと`date -s "2021-09-02 18:00:00"`というコマンドで完了するはずなのだが、それでも更新できなくて苦戦した。（ntpdサービスも停止していたのに...）
調査の結果、「VMのクロックにシステムクロックが同期されている」ことが原因であるとわかった。
勝手に同期される設定を変更してあげて、再度システムクロック更新を試みたら成功した。

```
#> vim /etc/sysctl.conf
/** 末尾に以下を記載 **/
# Allow the VM to update it's own clock, and do not use the DOM host clock.
xen.independent_wallclock=1

/** network（or networking）サービスを再起動 **/
#> /etc/init.d/network restart

/** 時刻を修正 **/
#> date -s "2021-09-02 18:00:00"
```

#### 参考にした情報

英語版Q&Aに同じような質問があり、今回はその情報を参考にしました。
https://superuser.com/questions/510691/linux-date-s-command-not-working-to-change-date-on-a-server

今回、様々な回答を寄せてくださった皆様、ありがとうございました。

Comment: なるほど、今回の場合は利用可能な clock source に `xen` がないので `xen.independent_wallclock` の設定は効かないだろうと思っていたのですが、`jiffies` でも有効なのですね。

Comment: `xen`も`jiffies`もほとんど理解してないので、もう少し勉強してみます。ご助力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $> date
> 2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 08:50:03 UTC
>
> $> date -s "2021-08-31 07:34:00"
> ```

`date`は念じた書式を理解してくれるわけではなく、明示的に書式を指定する必要があります。時刻調整であって日付を変える必要がない場合はroot権限で

```
#> date +%T -s "07:34:00"
```

ですかね。これは

```
$> date +%T
08:50:03
```

に対応します。

---

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5であっても`ntpd`は存在するわけで、本質的にはなぜこれが動作しないのかだと思います。その意味では

> ```
> 2021年  8月 31日 火曜日 08:50:03 UTC
> ```

という記述が気になりました。時刻が９時間ずれていませんか？ そしてその理由はタイムゾーンが設定されていないのではありませんか？ 08:50:03 UTC は日本時間の 17:53:03 を意味します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。お教えいただいた`date +%T -s "HH:MM:SS"`のコマンドを実行しても、変化はありませんでした。  
UTC時刻のタイムゾーンは敢えてUTCとしております。システム時刻は本当の時刻と40分ほどズレてしまっており、それを解消したい状況です。

Comment: `ntpd`は自分も把握しきれておらず、現在調査中です。ここはもう少し調べてみます。

Comment: 補足情報として、`man date(1)` には `-s, --set=STRING  set time described by STRING` と書かれていて、`STRING` のセクションには「The --date=STRING is a mostly free format **human readable date string** such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".」とあります。実際、Ubuntu Linux 21.04 で試してみると `date -s "2021-08-31 07:34:00"` という書き方でも時刻の変更が可能でした。ただ、ntpd などで時刻同期を実施している場合には変更しても戻されてしまいますけれども。

Comment: ありがとうございます。情報の記載し忘れていて申し訳ないのですが、ntpdは停止した上で`date`コマンドを実行しています。なのに、なぜか時間が更新されないという不思議な状況に。